# Появляются 2 файла вместо одного typescript

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Всем привет. Делаю проект на nest + typescript. Игрался с настройками в `tsconfig`, потом восстановил все назад но что-то сломалось. Теперь у меня количство файлов увеличилось вдвое. Так же, возможно, это связано с самим web storm, но это не точно).

tsconfig:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `"declaration": false,`??

Comment: ничего не изменилось)

Comment: Ну удалять их за вас никто не будет. Так что придётся вручную удалить все *.d.ts

Comment: блин, ну ладно, спасибо